# Including a .targets file in the universal app shared project to include a custom build action

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, sharpdx, win-universal-app

In separate Windows 8.1/Windows Phone 8.1 projects, including the SharpDX.targets file from the SharpDX repo includes all of its content build actions in each project. Doing the same in the shared project in a universal app doesn't work (project reloads successfully but tools are no in the Build Action list).

Is there an alternate solution to keeping the content in the shared project rather than keeping copies in each of the W8.1/WP8.1 projects just because there is no centralized way of building it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a shared project in a universal app is never really built. It's merely a container of files to be shared into each of the specific projects. If you have custom build actions, you need to include them in each specific project (that requires them).